# keeping drawn strings on jpanel

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to print the contents of an array of ints on the screen one at a time but keep the previous elements on screen, how can i do this? This is what i have so far which prints each element but doesnt keep the previous elements on the screen

```
import javax.swing.*;  
import java.awt.*;  

class test extends JFrame  
{  
  JPanel panel;  
  public static void main(String[] args)  
  {  
      test obj = new test();  
      obj.makeAnim();  
  }  
  public void makeAnim() {  
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
      setTitle("Animate");
      setResizable(false);  
      setSize(400,400);  

      Animate arr1 = new Animate();  
      Animate arr2 = new Animate();  
      //arr1.add(arr2);  
      getContentPane().add(arr1);  
      setVisible(true);  
      new Thread(arr1).start();  
      //new Thread(arr2).start();  
  }  
}  
class Animate extends JPanel implements Runnable  
{  
  int j = 1;
  int [] a = {1,2,3,5,6,7,2,1,10,99};  
  String temp; 

  public Animate()  
  {  
     setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,400));  
  }  
  public void run()  
  {  
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  

        temp = Integer.toString(a[i]);
        j++;
        repaint();  

        try {  
            Thread.sleep(2000);  
        } catch (Exception ex) {}  
    }  
  }  
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g)  
  {  

    super.paintComponent(g); 
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.setFont(new Font("Courier",Font.PLAIN, 20));
    g.drawString(temp, (50+(j*10)), 50);


  }  
}
```

Comment: If you want the painting to stay on the screen then you must do all of the painting in the paintComponent() method every time. Also, don't set the font and color in the paint method. Use the setFont(...) and setForeground(...) properties. Don't forget to accept previous answer if you want help in the future.

Answer (score 2):

There a number of problems your are facing.

Painting in Swing is stateless, that means what ever was previously painting during one cycle, will not appear in the next, unless you physically paint it.

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details.

Unless you synchronize you threads and paint routines (which is not advisable), you should never change the state of any variable that the paint methods may be reliant on out side of the Event Dispatching Thread.

Instead of using a `Thread` you should be using a `javax.swing.Timer`.

You may find [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) informative

You shouldn't be relying on "magic" numbers (such as the character width offset), you should be relying on the underlying system to provide you with useful hints.  In this case, you will want to look at [`FontMetrics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html)

You should also avoid using `setPreferredSize` and override `getPreferredSize`

Below is an example of how I might solve the same problem...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

class TestPaint02 extends JFrame {

    JPanel panel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                TestPaint02 obj = new TestPaint02();
                obj.makeAnim();
            }
        });
    }

    public void makeAnim() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Animate");
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(400, 400);

        Animate arr1 = new Animate();
        getContentPane().add(arr1);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public class Animate extends JPanel {

        int i = 0;
        int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1, 10, 99};

        public Animate() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(2000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    i++;
                    repaint();
                    if (i >= a.length) {
                        ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                    }
                }
            });
            timer.setRepeats(true);
            timer.setInitialDelay(0);
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.red);
            g.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, 20));
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            int x = 50;
            int y = 50;
            for (int loop = 0; loop < i; loop++) {
                g.drawString(String.valueOf(a[loop]), x, y);
                x += fm.stringWidth(String.valueOf(a[loop]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Im going to end up animating more than one array on the window so isnt Thread the better choice to have the animations start consecutively?

Comment: No.  Swing is not thread safe.  This means that it's impossible to predict what will occur if one or more threads attempt to update the UI.  You could use a `SwingWorker` instead.